# How can I dynamically create a RenderFragment within a Method Parameter?

Tags: c#, razor, blazor, blazor-webassembly, blazor-component

The following Code generates the output `<p>sample</p>` and shows how the compiler allows the creation of RenderFragments using regular razor code.

```
@stringFragmentWithParam("sample")

@code{
    private RenderFragment<string> stringFragmentWithParam = s => (__builder) =>
    {
        <p>@s</p>
    };
}
```

Now I want to use this concept create Extension Methods in the following manner (this example could yield `<div><p>sample</p></div>`):

```
// somewhere in a static class:
public static RenderFragment RenderInDiv(this string value, RenderFragment<string> fragment)
{
    // Omitted
}

@code {
    string somestring = "sample"
}

@somestring.RenderInDiv(s => (__builder) =>
    {
        <p>@s</p>
    })
```

But this doesn't compile. The compiler doesn't like the `<p>@s</p>` part, even though it's the exact same thing like in the previous example.

> Please note, that I know how to implement the `RenderInDiv()` Method, I'ts just a simplified example of my real usecase. I also know how to implement a component that does the same thing. **My Question is** how could I call methods like that directly building the Renderfragment inline? Because using the `RenderFragment` from the first example with the `RenderInDiv()` Method will work. `@somestring.RenderInDiv(stringFragmentWithParam)`

Answer (score 1):

it won't compile because it is already in C# context and Razor syntax is not allowed there.

You can instead keep the RenderFragment field in the Razor code and use it as a parameter.

```
@somestring.RenderInDiv(stringFragmentWithParam)

@code {
    string somestring = "sample";

    private RenderFragment<string> stringFragmentWithParam = s => (__builder) =>
    {
        <p>@s</p>
    };
}
```

... or you can create templates using only extension methods

```
@somestring.RenderInP().RenderInDiv()
```

...

```
public static class RenderFragmentExtensions
{
    public static RenderFragment RenderInP(this string parameter)
    {
        return (__builder) =>
        {
            __builder.OpenElement(0, "p");
            __builder.AddContent(1, parameter);
            __builder.CloseComponent();
        };
    }

    public static RenderFragment RenderInDiv(this RenderFragment innerFragment)
    {
        return (__builder) =>
        {
            __builder.OpenElement(0, "div");
            __builder.AddContent(1, innerFragment);
            __builder.CloseComponent();
        };
    }

    public static RenderFragment RenderInDiv(this string parameter, RenderFragment<string> innerContent)
    {
        return (__builder) =>
        {
            __builder.OpenElement(0, "div");
            __builder.AddContent(1, innerContent(parameter));
            __builder.CloseComponent();
        };
    }
}
```

... or static methods in razor page and calling them from anywhere.

```
@using static (the razor_page class - optional, depends on you)
@RenderInDiv(RenderInP(this.somestring))
```

...

```
@code {
    public static RenderFragment<string> RenderInP = parameter => (__builder) => 
    {
        <p>@parameter</p>
    };

    public static RenderFragment<RenderFragment> RenderInDiv = innerFragment => (__builder) => 
    {
        <div>@innerFragment</div>
    };
}
```

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to switch back to a Razor Context from within a c# context? For instance, I've tried wrapping the whole call with `@{ ... }` which will fix the syntax highlighting, but still fail to compile.

Comment: Also I wanna note, that I really like the Idea of building a `FluentRenderFragmentBuilder`  that allows to compose these fragments with c# code, without using the unhandy RenderTreeBuilder Syntax, but thats something I might create a new GitHub Package for. :)

Answer (score 0):

For maintainability create a component with the desired output:

SomeComponent

```html
<p>@Name</p>
@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string Name { get; set; } = default!;
}
```

Extension Method:

```cs
public static RenderFragment ToRenderFragment(this string name)
{
    return builder =>
    {
        builder.OpenComponent<SomeComponent>(sequence: 1);
        builder.AddComponentParameter(sequence: 2, name: "Name", name);
        builder.CloseComponent();
    };
}
```

If you have multiple components with the same parameters:

```cs
public static RenderFragment ToRenderFragment<TComponent>(this string name)
        where TComponent : notnull, IComponent, ISomeCommonInterface
{
    return builder =>
    {
        builder.OpenComponent<TComponent>(sequence: 1);
        builder.AddComponentParameter(sequence: 2, name: "Name", name);
        // Add all interface members.
        builder.CloseComponent();
    };
}
```

Example usage in a C# file.

```cs
internal class SomeClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public RenderFragment NameRenderFragment => Name.ToRenderFragment();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for adding this method to the thread as well. Perhaps I should add, that my goal with this question is to add syntax sugar, for special usecases. Which is why I want to be able to on create the RenderFragments using razor syntax, and pass them directly into any method.

Comment: You can't mix with .cs files. This is why I put the razor fragments in their own files that and maintainability of the fragments.

Comment: That's not what I meant. You can create `RenderFragments` with razor syntax within a razor file (refer to the first code example of my question). What I haven't figured out, is how to create these fragments inline within a Method call statement, that accepts a RenderFragment, without first declaring a local variable.